# External newtork card need reconnection (physical) after using Windows

Tags: networking, windows, network-manager

I have usb network card and after I use Windows and boot into Ubuntu there is no connectoins available, after I reattach card I see connection again.

Comment: Did you disable fast startup in windows? I guess windows puts the USB device in some kind of hibernation state while Ubuntu expects it to be turned off on boot.

Comment: @danzel yes, I did.